# F#5 or Fx5 in La Campanella m. 128?

Tags: piano, sheet-music, accidentals

[image: "La Campanella", m. 128]

In MuseScore version 3.6.2 I see it being F##5 indeed, but the next note in line is also F##, but looking into how it looks like in Piano visualiser that first one must be a mistake.

[image: m. 128 in MuseScore]

[image: m. 128 in Visualizer]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be F#5; the score in the Question contains an error.

Here is the same measure in the Busoni edition of the piece. The note has a # sign in front of it.

[image: "La Campanella", m. 128, Busoni edition]
(Image source: IMSLP, [Grandes études de Paganini, S.141](https://imslp.org/wiki/Grandes_%C3%A9tudes_de_Paganini,_S.141_(Liszt,_Franz)))

And again, from the Gárdonyi edition (1971)

[image: "La Campanella", m. 128, Gárdonyi edition]
(Image source: IMSLP, [Grandes études de Paganini, S.141](https://imslp.org/wiki/Grandes_%C3%A9tudes_de_Paganini,_S.141_(Liszt,_Franz)))

Comment: Breitkopf & Härtel and Ernst Pauer both have the typo then?

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников Yes. It goes all the way back to the first edition.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников the alternative conclusion, that there are supposed to be 12 perfect octaves with one diminished octave in their midst, is not tenable.

Comment: It's indeed a logical conclusion - what else! But could there have been a cautionary natural sign included (cancelling one of the sharps before) . Almost the whole piece is filled with accidentals, let's make it a full set...

Comment: I would only note that in the Gárdonyi (Bärenreiter) urtext the correction doesn't even merit a comment in the Critical Notes at the back of the volume. (Where editions still differ is in the *quasi cadenza,* m.77.)

Comment: @DjinTonic Thank you. I had hoped to find some critical commentary (or absence thereof), but didn't have access.